# Забайндить пустой объект

Tags: php, kohana

В виде есть форма, в ней возможны два варианта развития событий, объект передан из контроллера и нет объекта (по сути это два разных `action'a`. Естественно я забайндил объект в вид чтобы ни делать лишних проверок:

```
$object = ORM::factory('object',1);
View::factory('objectview')->bind('object',$object);
```

итого в форме напр. есть такой инпут:

```
<input type="hidden" name="object" value="<?=$object->id?>" />
```

Вызвав один `action` в котором есть объект, форма будет работать отлично, вызвав второй, будет выдано сообщение об ошибке, о том что такого объекта нету. (имеется в виду что вообще он не создается через ORM, но сам `bind('object',$object)` есть.

Собственно говоря вопрос в том как `забайндить/создать` пустой объект, который не существует, чтобы лишних проверок в форме ни делать?

**ошибка**
     ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: object

**решение**
Просто создать объект класса.

```
$object=ORM::factory('object');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то ругалось оно на попытку получить свойство `id` из пустой переменной, а значит:

```
$object = (object)array('id' => 0); // необходимое свойство
View::factory('objectview')->bind('object', $object);
```

Если `$object` - экземпляр ORM, то можно так:

```
$object = ORM::factory('Something'); // все свойства есть, но пустые
View::factory('objectview')->bind('object', $object);
```

Либо всё-таки добавить проверку, благо она не такая большая:

```
<?=isset($object->id) ? $object->id : 0?>
```

Comment: у меня очень много полей на форме.

Comment: тогда создайте его, но не вызывайте ``save()`` и будет у вас объект с пустыми свойствами

Comment: О, подошло! Я имею в виду что просто создал через `ORM::factory('object')`, без загрузки.

Comment: замечательно :)